# DASK Metadata mismatch found in 'from_delayed' JSON file

Tags: python, dataset, bigdata, dask

I'm just starting my adventure with `DASK` and land I'm learning on an example dataset in json format. I know that this is not the easiest data format in the world for a beginner :)

I have a dataset in the `json` format. I loaded the data via `dd.read_json` to dataframe and everything goes well. The problem occurred with, for example, the `compute()` or `len()` function.

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.

Partition type: `DataFrame`
+----------+-------+----------+
| Column   | Found | Expected |
+----------+-------+----------+
| column1  |   -   | object   |
| column2  |   -   | object   |
+----------+-------+----------+
```

I tried different things, but nothing helps. I don't know how to handle this error.

Please help, I will be very grateful !

Comment: The problem is that dask is infering the datatype for the given columns. You can set it using `dtype`.You can habe a look at this [library](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack) too

Comment: @user32185 thanks a lot. I changed the type of these two columns to `float` using the `astype` function. But now I'm getting a different kind of error:                                 `ValueError: could not convert string to float: y2122-9865-b432-986ty34924`

Comment: Is it happening on one columns only?

Comment: @user32185 no, it happens in two columns. These columns have "NaN" values, and the column type is object.

Comment: Ok, I somehow dealt with it, but in different way. At the beginning I loaded the json data to dask.bag using `json_data_bag = db.read_text (file_path) .map (json.loads)` and later I transformed it into a dataframe using `json_data_df = json_data_bag.to_dataframe ()`. For now it works :)

Answer (score 10):

My guess is that your JSON data has different columns in different parts of the data.  When Dask DataFrame loads your JSON data it looks at the first chunk of data to determine what the column names and datatypes are.  It then assumes that all of your data looks like this.

This assumption turns out to be wrong in your case and probably there is some column that only appears later on in the file.

You might consider increasing the size of the sample that Dask reads when determining metadata like column names.

```
df = dd.read_json(..., sample=2**26)
```

The default is 1MB (2**20)