# Synthetic column required by read_sql_table's meta

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I'm using Dask to transfer table data into parquet files. Some of my columns are nullable, and therefore I need to provide a schema when reading from the database and writing to parquet. When reading the data using `read_sql_table`, I create an empty pandas Dataframe, specifying the list of columns and the index, in order for each column to be treated as an `object` (nullable) instead of `int64` (ID columns).

```
 cols = [    
    "AFE_ID",
    "COST_ENTITY_ID",
    "COMMENTS",
    "LOCATION",
    "LOCATION_CODE",
    "CREATED_BY_ID",
    "CREATED_DATETIME",
    "MODIFIED_BY_ID",
    "MODIFIED_DATETIME",
    "LOCATION_NAME",
    "COMPANY_ID",
    "MILLIS_DELETED",
    "MILLIS_INACTIVATED",
    "DEFAULT_FLAG",
    "FREE_TEXT_FLAG",
    "LOCATION_ID__1", ## Why is this needed?   
    ]
type_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols,
                       index=pd.Index(name="LOCATION_ID", data=[], dtype="int64")
                       )
```

`LOCATION_ID` is the primary key of the table. Initially I did not include the last element in the `cols` list `LOCATION_ID__1`.  Subsquently when the data was read

```
table_df = ddf.read_sql_table(table=query,
                              index_col="LOCATION_ID",
                              uri=replica_uri,
                              schema="XXXXX",
                              meta=type_df,
                              )
```

I then encountered the error:

```
ValueError: Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.

Partition type: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`
+------------------+-------+----------+
| Column           | Found | Expected |
+------------------+-------+----------+
| 'LOCATION_ID__1' | int64 | -        |
+------------------+-------+----------+
```

There is no column in the table called `LOCATION_ID__1`; this is the "synthetic" column I'm referring to in the subject line. I first added this "synthetic" column to the start of `cols` and that did not work, but adding it to the end did. When the table was written out to parquet and I read it back in to verify, there was no `LOCATION_ID__1` column, just a `LOCATION_ID` as the index.

Does anyone know why this synthetic column exists? What purpose does it serve?

Dask: 2021.4.1
Pandas: 1.2.4
Numpy: 1.20.3
Pyarrow: 4.0.0
Dagster: 0.11.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DASK Metadata mismatch found in 'from\_delayed' JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992783/dask-metadata-mismatch-found-in-from-delayed-json-file)

Comment: So weird! Can you execute the same query (or the first 10 rows) using pandas directly?